# Check if asset exist in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, assets

How I can check if a specific asset exists in Flutter. I'm trying to load some images and sound files and I need to handle the case when these assets do not exist.

I need to check the existence because I have audio files and images for numbers from 1 to 1000. When I build my widgets I use a loop from 1 to 1000 to build it. and there are possibilities that the required file ( the image or the sound for the current number ) does not exist in the assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are using the `AssetBundle` class to load your data using the `load` method which takes `ByteData`, and when you use this method, it will throws an exception if the asset is not found.

Answer (score 5):

you can try my solution, if you use a simple Image.asset Widget:

```
Image.asset(
'assets/image.jpg',
 errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
                return Image.network('path');})
```

Comment: Still throws an "Unable to load asset: ... Exception caught by image resource service. The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:"

Answer (score 4):

Following Raouf suggestion I handled the case where the assets not exist.

Image loader widget:

```
Future<Image> _buildImage() async {
  String path = "assets/images/contents/${content.id}.jpg";
  return rootBundle.load(path).then((value) {
    return Image.memory(value.buffer.asUint8List());
  }).catchError((_) {
    return Image.asset(
      "assets/images/null.png",
      height: 250.0,
    );
  });
}
```

Using the Image widget inside my build method:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: _buildImage(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Image> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
              return snapshot.data;
            else
              return Image.asset("assets/images/null.png");
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Better not to call `_buildImage()` this way. Calling it from the `FutureBuilder()` may lead to it being called every frame. See documentation for `FutureBuilder` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an exception on the ```rootBundle.load``` line and the catchError section doesn't seem to get called. I also tried to put it all in try/catch but that didn't work either. This is very frustrating...

Answer (score 1):

For someone that Flutter IO Dev answer did not work because the exception still appears, this worked for me:

```
Future<Widget> getDevIcon(String path) async {
  try {
    await rootBundle.load(path);
    return Image.asset(path);
  } catch (_) {
    return SizedBox.shrink();
  }
}
```