# Flutter check if Asset image exists

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to conditionally load an asset image, only if it exists? Therefore you could load a default image if it does not exist in the Assets bundle.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908923/check-if-asset-exist-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do this without relying on catching an exception?

Answer (score 2):

One way you can check if the asset image exists is by trying to display it. If it throws an Exception, display a different widget instead.

```
Future<Widget> getAssetImage(String path) async {
  try {
    await rootBundle.load(path);
    return Image.asset(path);
  } catch (_) {
    return SizedBox(); // Return this widget
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can [check the AssetManifest.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555070/2497859) and cross-check the asset to be used with the list before trying to access it.